# SQL Server 2016 table partitioning

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Standard steps for adding a new partition are: create the file group, add the file, change partition scheme and function, rebuild tables (clustered index). But, if you don't have any data yet in the table that would belong in the new partition, do you really need to rebuild the tables? I don't believe so... 
Thanks!

Comment: Those are not the steps for adding a *partition*, but for adding new *partitioning*. (Adding a partition is typically done with `ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION ... SPLIT RANGE`, and no rebuilding is required as SQL Server will handle any data movement automatically). If you have no data at all, you can create the table with its partition scheme directly, without rebuilding anything, by specifying it in the `ON` clause (which is `ON [PRIMARY]` by default).

Comment: I want the new partition to reside in a separate file, that's why I need a new file group and file. This is about adding a new partition, that's why I said change (correct wording would be ALTER, yes, sorry for the confusion) the partitioning scheme and function (ALTER P SCHEME.... SET NEXT USED <new FG> and ALTER P FUNCTION SPLIT RANGE <value>) because they already exist. I do have data, just not the data that would qualify for the new RANGE values. (Continued)

Comment: So this is a new partition, according to your answer no rebuilding is necessary even if you have data that would go in the new partition, but I doubt that ALTER P SCHEME and ALTER P FUNCTION SPLIT would move that data? I believe that's why you need the REBUILD for. But when you don't have qualifying data for the new values yet, do you still need a REBUILD? Thanks.

Comment: No, you never rebuild the index. That would be madly expensive just for adding a new partition. If `SPLIT RANGE` results in data movement for existing data, then SQL Server will move the data right then and there. If no data movement happens (because the new partition is empty) then that's the end of it. The index is consistent with the partitioning scheme at all times.

Comment: So the SPLIT RANGE does move the data.. Thank you! If you post it as an answer, I can mark it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "rebuild tables" step is never necessary for changing partitioning through `ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION ... [MERGE | SPLIT] RANGE` whether or not the partitions contain data; SQL Server will move data between filegroups as necessary. The index is consistent with the partitioning scheme at all times. Admittedly the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-partition-function-transact-sql) could be a lot clearer on this; the only thing they mention currently is

> `ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION` repartitions any tables and indexes that use the function in a single atomic operation. However, this operation occurs offline, and depending on the extent of repartitioning, may be resource-intensive.

If you squint really hard you may infer from it that data gets moved as necessary, but it could be more explicit.